# fragment - navigation drawer - app stopped error

Tags: android-fragments

Greeting

When I click on the camera text, the app shows an error said "The application has stopped". How it can be fixed?

MaingActivity.java

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        CameraFragment cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
        FragmentManager manager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                cameraFragment,
                cameraFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Gallary",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have found it
Select contant_main.xml => click on icon refer Constrains

The code will be as the following

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.shakeralmoosa.nav1.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```